# Will cutting PVC pipe with a miter saw dull the blade?

Tags: pvc, cutting

I want to cut some 3" PVC with my miter saw and I'm wondering if this would dull my blade. I think its a 60 or 80 tooth Diablo blade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not!!  Go for it, but hang on tight to the pipe, it has a tenancy to roll in a chop saw.

Comment: Also watch out for flying pieces, especially when making small cuts (eg <2" off the end) as the blade can send the offcut a pretty good distance. I've also had central vac tube -- which is 2" thin-walled PVC -- actually shatter into several flying pieces from bringing the blade down too fast. Just a reminder to always wear eye protection!

Comment: Yep, go slow, don't rush the cut.